# NSMenuItem action is not executing

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenuitem

I am creating a status bar on my app and the menus show up fine, however it does not seem to access the actions that I have set up for it.

I am adding the status bar through a C function:

```
void MyFunction(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) {
    MyMenuItem* item = [[MyMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 1" action:@selector(doAction:) keyEquivalent:@"")];
    [item setBrowser:browser];

    NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
    [menu setAutoenablesItems:NO];
    [menu addItem:item];

    NSStatusBar *statusBar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
    MSStatusItem *statusItem = [statusBar statusItemWithLength:NSBariableStatusItemLength];
    [statusItem retain];
    [statusItem setImage:imageObj];
    [statusItem setTitle:@"Status"];
    [statusItem setHilightMode:YES];
    [statusITem setMenu:menu];      
}
```

Declaring the actions right above MyFunction():

```
@interfaceMyMenuItem : NSMenuItem {
    CefRefPtr<CefBrowser>_browser;
}

@property (nonatomic) CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser;
- (void)doAction:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation MyMenuItem
@synthesize browser = _browser;
- (void)doAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Doing action");
}
@end
```

Everything compiles just fine, So I think it might have something to do with creating the Items from a C function, but not properly setting up the interface.

Answer (score 10):

have you tried setting target of menuitem and implementing validateUserInterfaceItem?

```
MyMenuItem* item = [[MyMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 1" action:@selector(doAction:) keyEquivalent:@"")];
[item setTarget:self];
```

and

```
-(BOOL)validateUserInterfaceItem:(id<NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem>)anItem
{
    return ([anItem selector] == @selector(doAction:)); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I did not set [item setTarget:self]; I did not realize that I had to add this in.

Comment: I think you need to, if you setAutoEnableItems to NO.

Answer (score 0):

We need to set target.
Answer in swift

```
let item = NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(quitApp), keyEquivalent: "p")
item.target = self
```

and

```
@objc func quitApp() {
    NSApplication.shared.terminate(self)
}
```